# Child Fragment Not able to inflate Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i am trying to inflate or change menu from child fragment , but not able to do so.
The flow is like this .

If I try to inflate menu from activity (Main)--- work fine.
 if i try to infalte  menu from fragment (SecondFrag)----work fine
 if i try to inflate menu from child fragment of(SecondFrag)----do not work

Sample Code is like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Log.d("It has option mener of not", ""+hasOptionsMenu());
}




@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    Log.d("Option Menu", "Activity Option Menu");
    mActivity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.deal_detaisl, menu);
    Log.d("Option Menu", "Activity Option Menu");
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.deal_loc:
        mActivity.showMapFragment();
        break;

    case R.id.deal_loc_route:
        mActivity.showMapRoute();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: mActivity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.deal_detaisl, menu); is this line not working? Think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Why don't you use the inflater you get from the method?

Comment: remove 'targetSdkVersion' from manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.deal_detaisl, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This should work for you, try it.

Edit:
You should create a custom `Fragment` and make the fragments extend that custom `Fragment`. Then in your `Activity` for `onCreateOptionsMenu` you can get the current `Fragment` and call a public method for inflating a menu (call it whatever). After a chat discussion, your problem was solved.

Comment: I am putting log in my child fragments onCreateOptionsMenu , actually it is never get called

Comment: It should, since you have setHasOptionsMenu(true). I'll look into this.

Comment: Yes it should show log in onCreateOptionMenu method , well it wont Thanks if you look on it

Comment: @SureshBora: You are not using this approach in your Activity? Maybe that takes over.

Comment: Means .. In main activity i am not inflating any thing as i want my menu to be inflated only when my child fragment is added. Do i need to inflate the menu in activity also ?

Comment: No you don't need to. It's very strange, I tried to resolve your problem. But wasn't able to do so, If I find anything I'll leave you a comment.

Comment: Yes ,thanks  I am really looking some thing  from you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39490/discussion-between-carnal-and-suresh-bora)