# Add new option menu from child fragment of FragmentTabHost inside outer fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

When I used some nested fragments for my application, child fragment of the application cannot add new option menu by overriding onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) method(never hit this method).

Class hierarchy of application is as follow.

MainActivity.java(extends SherlockFragmentActivity)
(MainActivity include the following child fragments)

1. Fragment1.java(extends SherlockFragment)
2. Fragment2.java(extends SherlockFragment)

(Fragment2 include FragmentTabHost for adding following child fragments)

```
 i. ChildFragment1.java(extends SherlockFragment)

 ii. ChildFragment2.java(extends SherlockFragment)

 iii. ChildFragment3.java(extends SherlockFragment)
```

I can add new OptionMenu in Fragment1, Fragment2 by adding setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) and 
by overriding onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater)

But I cannot add new OptionMenu in ChildFragment1, ChildFragment2, ChildFragment3 because onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) method of child fragment classes are never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can call the onCreateOptionsMenu of child fragments and can also call onOptionsItemSelected by following code.

Fragment2.java

```
protected FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
    Fragment currentFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof BaseTabsPagerChildFragment)
        ((BaseTabsPagerChildFragment) currentFragment).inflateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Fragment currentFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
        if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof BaseTabsPagerChildFragment) {
            return ((BaseTabsPagerChildFragment) currentFragment).onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

BaseTabsPagerChildFragment.java

```
abstract class BaseTabsPagerChildFragment extends BaseSherlockFragment {
    public abstract void inflateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater);
}
```

ChildFragment1.java(extends BaseTabsPagerChildFragment.java)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
};

@Override
public void inflateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.message_actionbar_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean handled = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if (handled) {
        return true;
    }
    int itemId_ = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId_ == R.id.menu_item_compose) {
        launchCompose();
        return true;
    }
    if (itemId_ == R.id.menu_item_delete) {
        doDelete();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method manually. In your `Fragment2` implement following

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    ChildFragment frag = (ChildFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentBy...;
    if (frag != null) frag.inflateOptionsMenu(menu, new MenuInflater(mActivity));
}
```

In your `ChildFragment` then have

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public void inflateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.deal_detaisl, menu);
}
```

I found the solution in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39490/discussion-between-carnal-and-suresh-bora) folloing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447140/child-fragment-not-able-to-inflate-menu).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution can make to call onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) of child fragments(ChildFragment1, ChildFragment2, ChildFragment3)  but cannot call onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) of child fragments when we click on optionItem.